# android support lib 23.1.1 changes floating label color on setError()

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

is there a way to change the color of 'Password'? Basically, I prefer what support lib 23.1.0 had. I have a page that has multiple TextInputLayouts, and it would be hard to read if both hint and error are in red. please see the screenshot below.

[image]

there are a few fixes I want in 23.1.1, so please don't ask me to stay with 23.1.0. Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a change in library it would be difficult to manipulate it. Android has decided to go that way (changing the label color along with the hint's color) and will become a standard soon and users will get familiar with it as time passes by. Not much we can do about it, but adhere, as always.

**Workaround:**
Don't set the Labels field on the `TextInputLayouts`. keep it blank and put another `TextView` just above it with the desired color and properly align it. That will not change, of course.

As per my comment below, you could also try this:

Hint color wont change. Just checked. So you may want to remove label and just add hint as `android:hint="Enter password"`. The word Password in your screenshot is set in the Label and not as a hint.

Comment: but it's more like a bug to me. please see what google has in their MD [doc](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3YUJneko5VEsxQ2s/patterns_errors_userinput12.png)

Comment: can u also share the original page link ? this one is a direct link to image only. just want to read it.

Comment: [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/errors.html#errors-user-input-errors)  and please scroll to 'Error with floating text label' section

Comment: Those images all have hint only. No label. Hint color wont change. Just checked. So you may want to remove label and just add hint as `android:hint="Enter password"`

Comment: notice when '5555' is entered the hint is no more visible. The Label would have stayed and changed color too if it was set.

Comment: sorry, my bad. i meant the 'Error with floating text label' section.

Comment: check `Single-line with character counter` section on the same page where the color is seen to be changing.

Comment: arrr. you are right. but whats up with the 'Error with floating text label' section.

Comment: probably they missed updating it. Report it and gain some browny points. But the label changes color in my app too. had noticed it last month but was allright in my case so did not dig deeper.

Comment: alright, thanks Virus! i like what they have in 'Error with floating text label' section. gonna report and see if they can release an option to go with whichever is preferred by user

Comment: oh wait...please check 'Incompatible values' and 'Incompatible values' sections. looks like floating label is changed to red only if its being used as char counter

Comment: hmm... interesting. will need to try it out to confirm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100187/discussion-between-virus-and-user1865027).